# Is there a way to combine several txtboxes in a MouseEnter/MouseLeaves event etz?

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling

I have an example of a code i use in visual studio that changes the backcolor of a button when I have
MouseEnters and the same goes for MouseLeaves.

```
Private Sub txtbox1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbox1.MouseEnter

    txtbox1.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
    txtbox1.ForeColor = Color.White

End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub txtbox1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbox1.MouseLeave

    txtbox1.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
    txtbox1.ForeColor = Color.Black

End Sub
```

My question is, is there a way to combine all the txtboxes into one sub that controls
all txtboxes without get all om them effected when one txtbox is enterd etz.

I still want txtbox1 to be the only one to change color when mouse enters and so on.
Instead of having to create one mouserenter/leaves for every single txtbox.

I want something like:
private sub txt_mouseenter(sendes as object, e as eventargs) handles
txt1.backcolor = color.blue
txt2.backcolor = color.blue
end sub

But I dont want to all txtboxes to change when entering txtbox1.

I have a lot of different buttons and txtboxes and i'm very knew to coding in general
so I just have very small basic knowledge and need every tip i can get to simplify
things.

Can one use a module or a class to get this effect or anything else?

Tried to make a sub t_test(sender as object, e as evenargs) Handles t1.mouseenter
t1.backcolor = color.blue
t2.backcolor = color.blue
end sub

but as i already knew it made it so that both txtboxes where affected

Comment: Have an actual look at the code you have already. You have the `Handles` clause at the end of method declaration, then you have the method body on separate lines after that. As you might expect, the `Handles` clause is what specifies what events that method handles. If you want to handle multiple events, put them there. The body is not part of the `Handles` clause. Put whatever you want actually executed in the body. If you research that `Handles` keyword, I'm pretty confident that you'd find relevant explanation and examples.

Comment: Please don't apply irrelevant tags to your questions. This question has nothing at all to do with VS 2022 or VS Code. I bet you could find some other relevant tags(s), like "events" or "event handlers" or the like.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause) is the documentation for the VB.NET `Handles` keyword. It was the second result in a search for "vb.net handles". You shouldn't be posting a question without having done this sort of basic research first.

Comment: Instead of "attacking" me you can just nicely explain.
First of all, I said that im new to all of this and ive only posted/asked for help twice (this is the second).
I put the tags because I thought it was relevant to what program im using. Sorry for that..
The problem with people like you is that you make other people not wanting to ask for help. Dont be so aggressive and condescending.
But thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Have a nice day!

Comment: The problem with people like you is that you immediately assume that anything approaching criticism is an attack and decide that the issue is the attacker, rather than considering what you might have done to warrant the criticism in the first place and doing something about it. If you do the wrong thing, telling you that you did the wrong thing is not an attack. If no one tells you then you'll keep on doing the same wrong thing, which doesn't help you or those people who have to then deal with it. Now you know what to change so it will be better for everyone, including you.

Comment: There are multiple ways to give criticism and telling someone what they've done wrong. The way you write can seem aggressive and its very easy to misunderstand  over text.  But yea, im sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AddHandler Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) to add Handler for every textbox's MouseEnter event and MouseLeave event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler TextBox2.MouseEnter, AddressOf TextBox1_MouseEnter
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseEnter
    sender.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
    sender.ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub
```